# Nested required objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am attempting to write a unit test and am having an issue where each mocked object relies on another 3 objects. This looks something like this.

```
var objC = new Mock<IObjectC>(IObjectG, IObjectH);
var objB = new Mock<IObjectB>(IObjectE, IObjectF);
var objA = new Mock<IObjectA>(IObjectB, IObjectC, IObjectD);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's just mocks setup, can you provide sample of code which you are testing and describe expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of mocking types is so we can write tests without having to deal with complex dependency graphs, or having to worry about communicating with any external processes, so we can focus on writing fast, deterministic unit tests.  What that means is when you create a mock, the internal representation of that mock is of no concern to your tests; it's simply a proxy object that replaces a real implementation that your code would use in production.

That said, we still need to be able to configure those mocks to exhibit the behaviour we desire - for example, returning values, or throwing exceptions -  which is why we can configure setups on them with calls to `Setup()`.

Now, going back to your question, I'm wondering if what you're really describing is the situation where you want to call a mock to return another mock.  That can happen in scenarios such as wanting to return a mocked strategy from a mocked factory.  To do that, you'd have to setup the factory to return the strategy.  Something like this:

```
var factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory>();
var strategyMock = new Mock<IStrategy>();
var type = typeof(FakeConcreteStrategy);

factoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(type)).Returns(strategyMock.Object);
```

With the above, a call to the factory's `Create` method with a type of `FakeConcreteStrategy` will return the mocked strategy.  From there, you could do whatever you needed with the strategy, such as verifying a call to it:

```
strategyMock.Verify(x => x.DoWork(), Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are violating [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and creating system with the [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) of components. If you would stick to this law and make a method that only invokes members of:

1. The object itself.
2. An argument of the method.
3. Any object created within the method.
4. Any direct properties/fields of the object.

then you would not have the problem of complex test setup.

**BEFORE:** consider ATM class which talks to client's wallet:

```
public void ProcessPayment(Person client, decimal amount)
{
    var wallet = client.Wallet;
    if (wallet.TotalAmount() < amount)
       throw new BlahBlahException();

    wallet.Remove(amount);
}
```

with complex setup of

```
[Test]
public void AtmShouldChargeClientWhenItHasEnoughMoney()
{
    var walletMock = new Mock<IWallet>();
    walletMock.Setup(w => w.GetTotalAmount()).Returns(15);
    var personMock = new Mock<Person>(walletMock.Object);
    var atm = new Atm();

    atm.ProcessPayment(personMock.Object, 10);

    walletMock.Verify(w => w.Remove(10), Times.Once);
}
```

**AFTER:** Consider now method which talks only to members of its arguments (Law of Demeter #2)

```
public void ProcessPayment(IClient client, decimal amount)
{
    if (!client.TryCharge(amount))
       throw new BlahBlahException();
}
```

Not only code becomes simple and readable, but also test setup is simplified:

```
[Test]
public void AtmShouldChargeClientWhenItHasEnoughMoney()
{
    var clientMock = new Mock<IClient>();
    clientMock.Setup(c => c.TryCharge(10)).Returns(true);
    var atm = new Atm();

    atm.ProcessPayment(clientMock.Object, 10);
    clientMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

Note that there is no real classes involed anymore. We replaced Person dependency with abstract IClient dependency. If something will be broken in Person implementation, it will not affect ATM tests.

---

Of course, you should have separate test for Person class to check if it correctly interacts with wallet:

```
[Test]
public void PersonShouldNotBeChargedWhenThereIsNotEnoughMoneyInWallet()
{
    var walletMock = new Mock<IWallet>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    walletMock.Setup(w => w.GetTotalAmount()).Returns(5);
    var person = new Person(walletMock.Object);

    person.TryCharge(10).Should().BeFalse();
    walletMock.VerifyAll();
}

[Test]
public void PersonShouldBeChargedWhenThereIsEnoughMoneyInWallet()
{
    var walletMock = new Mock<IWallet>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    walletMock.Setup(w => w.GetTotalAmount()).Returns(15);
    walletMock.Setup(w => w.Remove(10));
    var person = new Person(walletMock.Object);

    person.TryCharge(10).Should().BeTrue();
    walletMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

Benefits - you can change implementation of Person class without breaking ATM functionality and tests. E.g. you can switch from wallet to credit cards, or check credit cards if wallet is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This might point to a flaw in the design of the code you're testing. That's not bad - that's a good thing. It might not be - the problem could be what you're trying to accomplish with the test.

If you're mocking `IObjectA`, why do you need to mock its dependencies? If the class you're testing depends on `IObjectA`, should it matter whether implementations of `IObjectA` have their own dependencies? One benefit of depending on an abstraction is that a class doesn't have to be concerned with the implementation details of its dependencies. In other words, all your class should care about is what `IObjectA` does. It shouldn't know or care if `IObjectA` even has dependencies, let alone what they do.

If your class "knows" that `IObjectA` represents a class with its own dependencies, then it's really depending on more than the interface. The problem might indicate that you should refactor your class so that it *only* depends on the interface, not the dependencies of classes that implement the interface.

---

If `IObjectA` has properties or methods that need to return implementations of other interfaces then you could create mocks for those interfaces, and then configure your mock of `IObjectA` to return those mocks.